Carry & Roll for Upfront CDS
We can decompose the P&L for a CDS Position as follows:
P&L = P&L(Carry) + P&L(Roll-Down) + P&L(Curve Shift)
For a fixed horizon (h), Notional (N) and CDS Spread for a maturity T (S(T)) we can find the following definitions of the first two terms in several research papers:
P&L(Carry) = h * N * S
P&L(Roll-Down) = (S(T) - S(T-h))*Risky PV01(T-h) (as seen from the cds curve today)
with the usual definition of Risky PV01 in the papers.
With this, we can back out the implied curve Shift to make the above P&L equal to zero. However, all papers and books I found describe these methods in the pre big bang CDS world (with par spreads instead of upfront CDS).
Question: Do you know any literature on how to rewrite these formulas for the upfront CDS case? Example:
If (e.g. as a protection buyer with standardized fixed coupon of 1% and quoted spread of 0.8%) we receive an upfront payment of U, how would you modify the Carry and Roll formula? Obviously, there are rates effects as I can reinvest the upfront but that's not my point (so assume rates are zero). As the upfront amount is based on the full maturity we probably should not take the full amount into account for the horizon h. Should we, e.g., amortize linearly?
It would be then interesting to back out the implied curve shift for the quoted spread in order to have zero P&L in the upfront case (this obviously will differ from the implied shift in the non-upfront case).

I don't quite understand the question. The carry is $h\times N\times$ running spread. If the running spread is the standard 100 bps or 500 bps, then this is the carry. Can you define the rolldown to be the entire P&L due to the passage of time minus the carry?

What I mean is this: Lets suppose the quoted spread for an entity is just 10 bps and I'm paying 100 bps standardized for it. Then I will be paid an upfront amount. When analyzing P&L scenarios for a horizon of, say, 6 months, I would see a P&L from time effect (=Carry + Rolldown). This provides a cushion for a potential negative P&L coming from a curve shift. If carry is calculated as you stated then this would not take into account the upfront I received for the significant overpaying of 90 bps on quarterly basis, right?

If you receive an upfront fee and invest it and earn some interest, or, conversely, if you pay upfront fee, and borrow money for that, and pay interest on that - that's not part of your CDS's P&L, although that's definitely something you should consider when analyzing whether to do a trade,
